# What graphic driver to choose?

Tags: drivers, graphics

Trying to install graphic driver on my ubuntu desktop (14.04).

"lspci -v" shows

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Process
or Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
```

But it doesn't tell me which of the drivers I should use in intel download page:
https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/13815/Intel-Graphics-Drivers-for-Linux-

Really not sure if mine should be 82810, 82815 or others.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily install this driver via additional drivers in Ubuntu.

Here is a [Link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47506/how-do-i-install-additional-drivers).

Comment: Thanks @nick, I can't get the login screen due to "The system run in low-graphic mode".